# Can we visit the Temple Mount?

Tags: travel, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I heard that even though the Temple Mount is under muslim authority, tourists are allowed in specific hours.

My question is from a Torah perspective - since this place was for the Kohanim, are we "regular" Jews allowed to visit the place? I would love to go there and feel the holiness of the place

Comment: The temple mount was _not_ only for _kohanim_ (when the _bes hamikdash_ was standing).

Comment: Hacham Yishak Shelit"A (YALKUT Yosef vol. 5 last page) holds it's an Isur Karet.

Comment: You should check out this article on the topic by R Aharon Lichtenstein (whose birthday is today Yom Yerushalayim) [Part 1](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak65/10a-halak.htm) [Part 2](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak65/10b-halak.htm) [Part 3](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak65/10c-halak.htm)

Comment: @HachamGabriel You must be missing a detail there.

Comment: @msh210 or ever, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are those that hold you may, however the majority of contemporary Poskim hold you may not.

http://www.templeinstitute.org/archive/25-01-05.htm

This link goes to a website that supports going to the Temple Mount.

http://www.templeinstitute.org/main.htm

Comment: Can you summarise some of these views in the body of your answer?

Comment: What is the reason of the poskim who hold you may not go? I always hear that "Gedolei HaPoskim ossur" but never heard their reasonings why. It seems to be political in nature though.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Ra'avad, Har Habayis (Temple Mount) does not have Kedusha nowadays, so there would be no halachik issue with visiting any part of it. However, most poskim assume like the Rambam that Har Habayis retains its kedusha even though the Beis haMikdash has been destroyed.

This means people can only visit areas that are allowed based on their level of taharah/tu'mah. Nowadays, we assume everyone is *tamei meis*, so md'oraysa no one can go into the **azara** (Temple Courtyard), and md'rabanan one cannot go past the **cheil** (a gate the encircled both the Azara and Ezras Nashim).

A person with a *tumah yotzei megufo* cannot go into Har haBayis. He therefore needs to immerse in a kosher mikvah beforehand, and he can then go in any area outside the cheil.

No one claims there is a *halachik* problem with someone who toveled from going on har haBayis outside the cheil. The issue they raise is that perhaps we don't know where the Mikdash and Azara were and one may accidentally go into it. However, there is a large area from the outside of har habayis to the azara, so this doesn't explain why one couldn't go a few feet into har habayis. (There is also both a tradition and other evidence that the Dome of the Rock is where the Kodesh haK'doshim  was.)

Many feel one shouldn't go on har habayis because Jews didn't go in the previous few centuries. However, this was because Jews were banned from going on it. Previously, when Jews were allowed to go on Har Habyis, many did so, such as the Rambam and the Radvaz.

While many rabbis say one should not go on har haBayis, the reasons are not so clear-cut, and the basic halacha does allow it. Some Rabbis feel its important *to* go on har haBayis, since it shows the Jews still care about it, and it is an opportunity to keep the mitzvah of mora'ah (reverence) for the mikdash, and the mitzvah of distinguishing between the permitted and forbidden areas.

It is important that one who goes on har haBayis knows the basic halachos of tumah/taharah, which areas one can go, and the halachos of mora'ah (e.g. no shoes allowed).

See also:
http://www.ou.org/torah/article/tzarich_iyun_har_habayit
http://templemountcenter.com/Aliya_English.html

Comment: The RaMbaM didn't go on the Har HaBayith. http://sefertoldothadam.blogspot.com/2013/02/did-maimonides-actually-ascend-temple.html?m=1

Comment: If I recall correctly exception is made when there is purity on a national scale, which is the case here. If I can find a source I'll post it

Comment: The Rambam definitely went on the Har HaBayis.https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ozfud9E9hc0