# May a non-Jew ascend the Temple Mount today?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

[It is forbidden](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28591/4704) for a Jew who is impure to enter certain parts of the Temple Mount; many authorities prohibit entering it nowadays at all.

What about a non-Jew? Is someone who isn't Jewish permitted to ascend the Temple Mount nowadays?

Comment: Why would a non-Jew who's only obligation is the Noahide laws (which, yes, include many other concepts, but not the hilchos hamikdash) be bound by our halachos during a zman churban?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky What does zman churban have to do with anything?

Comment: Because when the Beis Hamikdash is built we have an obligation to keep people OUT of it. Now we (as a religion, not a country) have no real authority over it.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Pretty sure you just made that up. Nearly all Rishonim hold Kidsha L'Atid Lavo so it's still fully holy. (Please remember to ping me `@DoubleAA`.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct. I'm not disputing that. I am pointing out that the mitzvah is to ***keep non-Jews out of the kodesh areas of the Temple,*** something that is OUR obligation and one that we cannot accomplish at the present time.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Nothing to do with zman churban. Just having to do with yad yisrael tekifa.

Comment: @DoubleAA see the first part of my statement - ***We*** have the obligation, not them.

Answer (score 3):

Jews who are impure from a corpse and non-Jews can enter the same parts of the Temple Mount. (Rambam Biat Mikdash 3:5)

In the Temple times a non-Jew would be killed for entering prohibited parts of the complex. At least, that's what [the sign there said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Warning_inscription).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is a prohibition on the non-Jew or an obligation on Jews to keep them out.

Comment: The sign may refer to death by the hand of heaven (as the sign said "death which will ensue"). It may not mean that the court would put the person to death.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom Certainly. I never claimed otherwise.